# Installing Apatana on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, aptana

I just downloaded Eclipse and am trying to install Aptana.

I choose help, install new software, and enter

http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install

But I get:

> HTTP Server 'Internal Error':
>   http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install/content.xml HTTP
>   Server 'Internal Error':
>   http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install/content.xml
>   HttpClient connection error response code 500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue with the download site yesterday.  It should be operational now.

Answer (score 0):

the url is missing a "/" at the end. I had the same issue using their "copy to clipboard" feature.
use: http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install/